# gmaps4rails version 2 build method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I installed gmaps4rails for my Rails app, ran the generator, and required the two files like this in my application.js file, along with underscore.js

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps
```

adding, as instructed on github https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails, these dependencies in layout.html.erb

```
 <script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

When I tried to create the demo map from the github page with this code, I got an error that the object doesn't have a `build` method.

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'build'

```
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers([
    {
      "lat": 0,
      "lng": 0,
      "picture": {
        "url": "https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/img/uploads/addon_icons/13/13028-64.png",
        "width":  36,
        "height": 36
      },
      "infowindow": "hello!"
    }
  ]);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

Indeed, when I look inside the `base` file that I require in the manifest file there is no `build` method for that object.

How does one create a map in the new version for gmaps4rails?

Update
the github account for gmaps says to require gmaps this way, but when I do it says'couldn't find file 'gmaps/google'

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
```

Comment: In v2, `gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base` doesnt exist

Comment: I've made a video tutorial, link available in gem's github repo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use these requires in the assets pipeline

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
```

Remember that you will need to add underscore.js manually or using a gem in order to use it.

Comment: @BrainLikeADullPencil then you didnt install v2. Besides, notice you dont need to run the generator

Comment: Whats the version of the gem that you are using?  A very good practice is to always require the gems in your gemfile using the specific version of the gem that you need: Example gem 'gmaps4rails', '2.0.3'

Comment: @apneadiving I also have same problem,it says 'couldn't find file 'gmaps/google' ' how to install v2?

Answer (score 3):

For the error:

```
couldn't find file 'gmaps/google'
```

I found I simply had to do a bundle update gmaps4rails, as I had been using a v1.5.6 instead of the more recent 2.0.4.

Answer (score 1):

In your app directory use

```
rails g gmaps4rails:copy_js
```

or

```
rails g gmaps4rails:copy_coffee
```